# meaning of phrasal verb "put something out"

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I see somebody, say a man, in my home and then "***I put him out***".

To native speaker, or whoever can speak English well,
Does the example sentence convey meaning that:

> 1. I make him go out so he's now outside my home,
> 2. I cause him extra work he does for me, or
> 3. I make him unconscious ?

Dictionary says that the phrase can be used in such meanings except example #1, because in dictionary, the construct of how the verb is used is "*put + something + out*".

In this context, does this phrasal verb has similar meaning to "***take + somebody + out***"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sense 1 is used when talking about pets, particularly cats

> I put the cat out for the night.

Means I made the cat go outside.  It is not used about people.

The meaning of "I put him out" is unclear.  It lacks context. I don't recognise what sense 2 means, but sense 3 would only be used in the context of a fist-fight.

> There was a man in my house.  I fought with him, and I finally put him out by hitting him over the head with a poker.  He was still down when the police arrived.

"Put out" can also mean "Inconvenience"

> Would it put you out if I asked you to drive me to London tomorrow?

or "defeat in a knock-out tournament":

> Nadal put Sampras out in the second round.

There are lots of senses of "put out".  There isn't any way of knowing what "I put him out" means.  It is not particularly related to "take out".

Comment: Presumably Definition 2 is meant to be the 'inconvenience' sense.

Comment: @KateBunting exactly!